# What is the type of decltype(this) in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, this, decltype

Apparently clang thinks `decltype(this)` is a pointer to the cv-qualified class, while gcc thinks it is a *const reference* to a pointer to the cv-qualified class. GCC only thinks `decltype(&*this)` is a pointer to the cv-qualified class. This has some implications when it is used as the typename for a template. Consider a hypothetical example:

```
template<typename T>
class MyContainer {
    /* ... */
    template<typename ContainerPtr>
    class MyIterator {
        ContainerPtr container;
        /* ... */
    };
    auto cbegin() const
        -> MyIterator<decltype(&*this)> { return { /* ... */ }; }
    auto cend() const
        -> MyIterator<decltype(this)> { return { /* ... */ }; }
};
```

In this example, one implements a custom container of `T`. Being a container, it supports iterators. In fact, two kinds of iterators: `iterator`s and `const_iterator`s. It would not make sense to duplicate the code for these two, so one could write a template iterator class, taking either a pointer to the original class `MyContainer<T> *` or a pointer to the const version `MyContainer<T> const *`.

When `cbegin` and `cend` are used together, gcc errors out, saying it deduced conflicting types, while clang just works fine.

Comment: Evaluating `this` gives an rvalue. You cannot, for example, take the address, as in `&this`. If `this` were a const-reference, you could take the address.

Comment: `this` is a prvalue of type `X cv*`, where `cv` corresponds to the `cv` in `R my_foo() cv;`. Are you sure Clang thinks that `this` is a cv-qualified pointer, and not a pointer to cv-qualified `X`?

Comment: @Xeo, sorry, it should be a pointer to cv-qualified class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay, here is what I found in the standard ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) though:

> **7.1.6.2 Simple type specifiers [dcl.type.simple]**
>
> 4   The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>     — if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an
>   unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type
>   of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e`
>   names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
>     — otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where
>   `T` is the type of `e`;
>    — otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue,
>   `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
>    —
>   otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.
>  The operand of the
>   `decltype` specifier is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5).

and

> **5.1.1 General [expr.prim.general]**
>
> 3   If a declaration declares a member function or member function
>   template of a class `X`, the expression `this` is a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to *cv-qualifier-seq* `X`” between the optional *cv-qualifer-seq*
>   and the end of the *function-definition*, *member-declarator*, or
>   *declarator*. It shall not appear before the optional *cv-qualifier-seq*
>   and it shall not appear within the declaration of a static member
>   function (although its type and value category are defined within a
>   static member function as they are within a non-static member
>   function).   [ *Note:* this is because declaration matching does not occur
>   until the complete declarator is known. — *end note* ] Unlike the object
>   expression in other contexts, `*this` is not required to be of complete
>   type for purposes of class member access (5.2.5) outside the member
>   function body. [ *Note:* only class members declared prior to the
>   declaration are visible. — *end note* ]

The previous reference to §9.3.2 is an error, since that deals with the *body* of a member function, as pointed out below [in a comment by MWid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021292/what-is-the-type-of-decltypethis-in-c/20021356?noredirect=1#comment29898712_20021356).

> <del>**9.3.2 The `this` pointer [class.this]**
>   
>   1   In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the
>   keyword `this` is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of
>   the object for which the function is called. The type of `this` in a
>   member function of a class `X` is `X*`. If the member function is
>   declared `const`, the type of `this` is `const X*`, if the member
>   function is declared `volatile`, the type of `this` is `volatile X*`,
>   and if the member function is declared `const volatile`, the type of
>   `this` is `const volatile X*`.</del>

So it looks like gcc is wrong.

Comment: Note: Your original quote seemed to come from an old draft (older than [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), the last public draft before standardization). In the actual C++11 Standard the final wording of 7.1.6.2/4 is *slightly different* (the draft closest to the Standard is [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), which is basically the C++11 Standard + [editorial fixes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3338.html)). I have thus suggested an edit. But the difference has no effect on the question.

Comment: This answer doesn't apply to the question! `this` is **not** used in the body of a function and hence §9.3.2 has nothing to do with the question. The relevant part of the spec is §5.1.1/3. But anyway, it's a bug in gcc < 4.9.

Answer (score 18):

`this` is a *prvalue*, so `decltype(this)` should always be plain `X*` (or `X cv*` / `cv X*`). The addition of `const&` seems to be a bug in GCC (tested with g++ 4.8.1), which happens only for a class *template* (not for a "plain" class) and only *inside the trailing return type* (not inside the body of the member function): [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ede62afe18375385). This seems to be fixed in GCC 4.9 (experimental), you can test [here](http://gcc.godbolt.org).

Comment: Okay, so apparently the problem that prompted me to ask this question is highly specific and localised…